# how to know when conversion is done when using ffmpeg php?

Tags: php, file-upload, ffmpeg

i am converting some videos using this syntax. e

```
exec("ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv", $out);
```

verything works ok, just that i don't know when the files are ready.

`print_r($out)` doesn't seem to return anything

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the output that ffmpeg produces into a separate text file. This text file is produced once ffmpeg finishes it's conversion. You can use the following command:-

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -ar 22050 -ab 32 -f flv -s 320x240 video.flv 2> path/to/log.txt
```

Then in PHP you can just run a check to see if that log file exists yet or not, if it does then it's finished converting :)